# What is the Dropblock app from OmniIndex?

Tags: security, blockchain

What is Dropblock and what does it do? I am looking for a data analytics platform that uses blockchain for security and can be used with sensitive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@svdoug hi. Thanks for the question. I will straight away state that I have a vested interest as the CEO of OmniIndex so I am obviously very biased.

So What is Dropblock? Dropblock is our secure Web3 file sharing and access app that runs on mobile devices and within Google Workspace and sits on top of the OmniIndex Web3 Distributed Data Platform, which is a Fully Homomorphic data platform.

Dropblock for Google Workspace allows you to run basic analytics directly from the blockchain in to Google sheets and has both ODATA and SQL connectors built in to enable you to access your data. For more complex analytics you can directly pull from Google Sheets into Big Query to allow analytics from within Looker and Tableau.

I hope that this helps answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Dropblock is an app that uses the OmniIndex API / SDK; there is a full api specification on swagger here [swagger api](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis-docs/OmniIndexAPI/OmniIndex/1.0.0)

Key features are 1) homomorphic encryption and search 2) blockchain
These two things should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Dropblock is also a mobile storage app! It gives users 5GB of Web3 storage for free.

To answer your question, it can 100% be used for sensitive data as the blockchain data storage combined with its FHE technology fully protects data from ransomware and other attacks.

While it is not predominantly designed for analytics, the free app does include some basic analytics of your encrypted data - without decrypting it! This type of encrypted analytics is unique to OmniIndex. The encrypted analytics on the Dropblock mobile app includes sentiment analytics, and context analytics.

Because the insights are generated by analyzing the encrypted data, there is no risk of exposure for your sensitive data. This is an upgrade on end-to-end encryption which requires data to be decrypted before it can be searched or analyzed.

I hope this helps! I got this info from https://www.omniindex.io/dropblock-for-mobile/ and from my personal experience working for OmniIndex.

Comment: is there a date for the release of the dropblock for mobile app?